# How Should I Implement Security On UDP Socket

Tags: c++, security, sockets

I'm working on a peer to peer networking application but I cannot solve how I'm going to provide security on UDP sockets. 
I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I don't which method I should choose to implement security.
My idea is to generate RSA keys between every peer and share these keys over an insecure socket at first and keep the connection secure with those keys. But I'm not sure about how to implement RSA and if this is the most secure way to go.
I'm using C++ for this project by the way

Thank you very much

Comment: Afaik RSA is a cypher that cannot be decrypted if part of the data is lost or if its received out of order, so you may have a problem using it with UDP.

Comment: I guess you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [DTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security), the Datagram TLS.

It is like the TLS protocol that you know from HTTPS and various other secure point-to-point communication links, but it is implemented over UDP. You will find it already implemented in various libraries including GnuTLS and OpenSSL.

From the security point-of-view, one major difference between TLS and DTLS is that TLS defines an ill-formed message as an unrecoverable error, whereas DTLS specifically allows the connection to continue in this case. This makes the protocol more sensitive to even slight coding errors (think [Lucky Thirteen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Thirteen_attack)), so you had better not try to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm looking into it. Would you recommend OpenSSL or GnuTLS?

Comment: @FatihBAKIR I cannot recommend one over the other, they are both serious libraries.

Comment: OpenSSL is the most popular one, it is used by Firefox, Apache and many other big softwares. I don't know much about the others so I'd stick to that.

Comment: Thank you again then, I will take a look at both of them and probably stick with the openssl